# How to send and receive JWT token?

Tags: javascript, python, authentication, jwt

Trying to verify user's token.

How I'm making a request on the client side (js + react):

```
axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/verify', 
        headers: { authorization: sessionStorage.getItem('token') },
        data: {}
    })
        .then(function(response) {
            // ...
        });
```

How I'm receiving a request on the server side (python):

```
@app.route('/verify', methods=['POST'])
def verify_user():
    token = request.headers.get('Authorization')
    payload = jwt.decode(token, SECRET_KEY)  // error here
    // ...
```

Why do I get this error? :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
........
jwt.exceptions.DecodeError: Signature verification failed
```

Thank you in advance.

p.s. the token is sent correctly

---

**EDIT:**

Found the causer of the mistake:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def get_user():
    // ...
    token = jwt.encode({'some': 'payload'}, 'secret', algorithm='HS256')
    return token // when I return the token here, it becomes slightly reduced
```

real token:

```
b'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzb21lIjoicGF5bG9hZCJ9.Joh1R2dYzkRvDkqv3sygm5YyK8Gi4ShZqbhK2gxcs2U'
```

the reduced token I return:

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzb21lIjoicGF5bG9hZCJ9.Joh1R2dYzkRvDkqv3sygm5YyK8Gi4ShZqbhK2gxcs2U
```

How do I need to send generated jwt token to client to fix that?

Comment: if the token is sent correctly what's the problem? signature not being verified isn't really a bug

Comment: @azium just don't understand, why is the signature not verified...

Comment: make sure you're encoding and decoding it correctly

Comment: It's hard to help you troubleshoot this without an example of what the token looks like before you send it, and what it looks like when it arrives on the server side.  Can you please add that information to your post?

Comment: @MattMorgan edited, thank you. It arrives successful to the server. I just can't send correct token on the client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a string-vs-bytes encoding issue.  To decode a byte string:

```
str = byte_string.decode('UTF-8')  # turns b'123' into '123'
```

To encode the string to bytes:

```
byte_string = str.encode('UTF-8')  # turns '123' into b'123'
```

You probably need to `encode` the incoming string to bytes before you pass it to `jwt.decode()` like so:

```
jwt.decode(token.encode('UTF-8'), SECRET_KEY)
```

There are other encodings besides UTF-8, but that will probably be what you need.

Comment: fixed that, thank you. Now the tokens are completely the same, but, unfortunately, I am getting the same error jwt.exceptions.DecodeError: Signature verification failed

Comment: oh no, I just used different keys... Thank you one more time!

Comment: Awesome.  We're using JWTs in production applications and finding them useful and easy to work with.